# how to interrupt a process in make without interrupt make process

Tags: process, makefile, gnu-make, kill

I have this bit from a makefile, where I start with with the rule "debug" the QEMU, but where I need interrupt the QEMU with kill -9, the make kill too:

```
debug: ${BINDIR}/main 
    ${QEMU} -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic  -kernel $^ -s -S
    $(MAKE) sane

gdb: ${BINDIR}/main 
    ${GDB} ${BINDIR}/main

sane:
    stty sane
```

how to interrupt a process in make without interrupt make process?

Comment: So you want to interrupt a process started in a make file, but it should not terminate your build?

Comment: In "debug" target I need interrupt the qemu and to follow execute the "sane" target, but if I kill the process with kill -9, the "sane" target not is executed.

Comment: Try launching the `${QEMU}` in background by appending `&` and then try to interrupt

Comment: Using in background, control returns immediately to make running then immediately the target sane, so the goal is to correct the failures of the terminal left by qemu, are not made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to interrupt a process in make without interrupt make process?

GNU Make reacts upon the exit status of the command. To force Make to ignore the exit status of the command and proceed further, simply put `-` character before the command:

```
debug: ${BINDIR}/main 
    -${QEMU} -M versatilepb -m 128M -nographic  -kernel $^ -s -S
    $(MAKE) sane
```

Now, if you kill the QEMU, `make` would still report that the process has terminated abnormally, but would go on executing the rest, in this case the `$(MAKE) sane`.

Comment: Thanks, 
As simple.
:)
That's perfect.